# Passing data from view to Layout in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I'm brand new to CodeIgniter, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious here.

I'm comfortable with sending data from a controller to a view file using `return view('default/blog/index', $data);`. My issue is accessing the same data in a layout file which is extended by the view file using `<?= $this->extend('layouts/default'); ?>`.

For example, if I insert `<?= $data['content'] ?>` in my view file, it displays as expected. If I insert the same code in the layout file that is extended by my view file, I get the "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" exception.

What am I missing that will allow me to access my data from within the layout file?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

So in my BlogController I've got

```
class BlogController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $model = new Blog();

        $data = $model->getBlog();

        return view('default/blog/index', ['data' => $data]);

    }


    public function item($slug = null){

        $model = new Blog();

        $data = $model->getBlog($slug);

        return view('default/blog/item', ['data' => $data]);

    }

}
```

And then in my item.php and index.php files, I have

```
<?= $this->extend('layouts/default', ['data' => $data]); ?>
```

My Blog Model's getBlog() method:

```
public function getBlog($slug = false)
{
    if ($slug === false) {
        return $this->orderBy('bs_created_dt', 'desc')->findAll();
    }

    return $this->where(['bs_slug' => $slug])->first();
}
```

When I use the debug toolbar to inspect the data, it is showing as expected, and I can display it in the view files, but not in the layout file.

Comment: Please share the Controller method returning the View (`view('default/blog/index', $data);`) with the contents of `$data`.

Comment: Just added above. Thanks.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75372069/edit) and share your Model's method `Blog::getBlog(...)` as well.

Comment: Is `'content'` a *column name* on the `blogs` database table? Does your web URL have a *'slug'* or not?

Comment: The actual content column name is 'bs_content_text' - I had just removed the prefix and suffix either side for the purpose of asking the question.

When I use a url with a slug, I get a single blog item. When I use a url without a slug, I get the index of blog posts. In both cases, the data is being successfully passed to the view file and displayed. The issue is when I then try to pass data from the view to the layout using `$this->extend(...)` like above.

Comment: Since you're **not** passing a "slug" in `$data = $model->getBlog();`, this Model method returns an array of blogs (`->findAll()`). So, in your View file,  I don't get how you access that array using `<?= $data['content'] ?>`

Comment: On the index page, I used `print_r($data[0])` to test. This works in the view file, but not in the layout file.

Comment: I just tested your analogy locally. Any variables/data passed along with the View are still accessible in the Layout it extends with no extra work done. So, this *isn't* reproducible in my case.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I'm going to create a new project from scratch and see if the same thing happens, as I'm at a complete loss right now.

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter, you need to pass data also in an extended file called layouts.

Because you want to access data inside the extended file and for that, you just need to pass data to that file.

So replace the line of code of extended view with this :

```
$this->extend('layouts/default', ['data' => $data]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, I've already tried this and I get the same exception when I try to use the variable in the layout file.

Comment: I think you need to debug data varibale inside layouts file and check the error what it is.

Comment: Yeah, that's the bizarre thing. When I comment out the line that is causing the exception and then check the data array using the debug toolbar, it is showing all of the expected information, and it can all be accessed from within the view file - it's just as soon as I try to access it from within the layout file that it throws the exception.

I feel like what you have suggested should work.

Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: `system/View/View.php` The `extend(...)` method **doesn't** accept a second parameter. [`public function extend(string $layout)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/0a4209e1f11a9c9e96526282be544922ee59c14d/system/View/View.php#L365)

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - absolute rookie mistake.

I'm working off of a pre-existing template, and the previous developer had overwritten the `$data` variable in layout file before where I was trying to use it.

I'm off to stand in the corner for a while.